# Correlation between ActiveMQ Artemis paging and message priority

Tags: paging, activemq-artemis

As the title says - is there any correlation between ActiveMQ Artemis paging and message priority? In other words - is message priority applied against the page to which the message belongs or message priority applies "globally"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Priority is enforced for messages *on the queue* (i.e. in memory). Technically speaking, messages are paged at the *address* level which means they are not actually on the queue yet. Once messages are depaged and are put on the queue then priority is enforced.